# Oracle JDBC driver escapes \n to \\n at time to select data

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I'm trying to find a explanation why Oracle driver, by default, escapes end-line character "\n" to a escaped string "\\n", that makes the "\n" to show up when I print it. I'd also like to get some suggestions on how to deal with it in a elegante way besides simply replacing "\\n" to "\n" before printing it.

extra info:
- Oracle driver: ojdbc6.jar
- Java 1.6.0_18 and 1.7.0_45

Example:
- DB "column1" data = line1\nline2\nline3

```
java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT column1 FROM TABLE1");  
java.sql.ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();  
while (rs.next()) {  
   rs.getString(1); // it returns line1\\nline2\\nline3 
}
```

Appreciate any help,
Cheers

Comment: Show a SSCCE demonstrating what you mean.  http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: I just edited and put the example you ask for Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen. Please let me know if you nedd something more. Tks!

Comment: And how do you determine what the return value is?  System.out.println?

Comment: Yes Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, and also debuging the code thru Eclipse IDE. If I just replace "\\n" to "\n" in the returned value I get the expected result.

Comment: And the value in the database is correct?  I.e. that the `\n` you want is stored as a newline in the database and not as two characters - "\" and "n" ?

Comment: Yes, it's stored as a new line (\n). that's the result getting the value thru sqlPlus:  aaaa\nbbbb\ncccc

Comment: So, no, it is not stored as a newline, but as two characters - the \ and the n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the output from SQL*Plus shows \n and not actually starts a new line, then you have stored the two characters "`\n`" in your database and not an actual newline.

See http://www.unix.com/unix-advanced-expert-users/56212-sqlplus-output-new-line-character.html where the asker wants to get rid of actual line feeds in his database.

Comment: yeah! That's the trick! If you don't insert the new-line character but \n, OJDBC does the necessary to print exactly what is in the DB, escaping the slash of \n. Inserting chr(10) at time to insert does the magic. But how to deal with inserts being made by OJDBC?

Comment: Fix your original code which inserted the data and reinsert, or write a loop that fixes all records or parse the returned string converting \+n into \n.

Comment: That's my question ... how to fix the code in java that inserts the new-line character? Assuming I'm inserting a string in a VARCHAR column, how would such string, that contains new-line character, look like in java?

Comment: No.  Your question is about the code that asks the database about the previously inserted and broken value.

Comment: Ok, sorry I was not clean when I said "That's my question". I was talking about the question I just did (...But how to deal with inserts being made by OJDBC?)

Comment: For the main question you already gave me the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Open a new question and provide a sscce of the code in question.